# Cannot assign value to a variable in truffle console and other problems

Tags: truffle

I'm trying to do very basic things with Truffle 3.4.6 console. I've been able to successfully compile and migrate a contract and access its contents using both:

```
CoinCrowdsale.deployed()
CoinCrowdsale.at("0x327d1b04ea59035626438b84ea03a543d38662e0")
```

But then, there're things from the examples I cannot do. For example, assign a value to a variable:

```
var crowdsale = CoinCrowdsale.at("0x327d1b04ea59035626438b84ea03a543d38662e0")
Truffle v3.4.6 (core: 3.4.6)
Solidity v0.4.13 (solc-js)
```

The result of the assignation is the software version?? Of course, it's not been assigned at all:

```
crowdsale
Please specify the type of item to create. Example: truffle create contract MyContract
```

I've got more problems:

```
> truffle(development)> CoinCrowdsale.deployed().then(inst => {
> crowdsale = inst }); undefined
```

and then, again, inst is never assigned to crowdsale variable nor can access it in the console.

What am I doing wrong? Truffle docs are not helping so much...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I maybe am affected by this bug:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-core/pull/29

I've been told the fix will be released by the next Monday. I'll try again then.

Comment: Definitely it was the issue pointed before.

Answer (score 0):

it should be working like this, if you're in the truffle console:

```
CoinCrowdsaleInstance = CoinCrowdsale.deployed()
CoinCrowdsaleInstance.then(function(instance) {return JSON.stringify(instance.abi);})
CoinCrowdsaleInstance.then(function(instance) {return instance.yourFunction(); })
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work with my console version. It's a bug in the console to be fixed in a couple of days.